# Software for raspberry pi for live streaming of IP camera on laptop

Tags: windows, linux, raspberry-pi

I have connected raspberry pi to my IP camera and pi is connected wireless to the laptop. I want the live stream on my laptop (Windows 10 but if you have a solution for Ubuntu then it will be helpful as well).

I came to know about Gstream and net-cat but none of them seems to be working properly.